# Shrinking VARCHAR with MODIFY: data alignment and potential for data loss

Tags: mysql, shrink, varchar

I'm using `MODIFY` to change (shrink) a number of `VARCHAR` fields of various lengths in various tables. In each case, the field is called `ip` and is a textual representation of an IPv4 or IPv6 address. To that end, I want to set the fields to `VARCHAR(45)`, which permits an IPv6 address using IPv4 tunnelling. My syntax, for completeness:

`MODIFY ip VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL default ''`

My question is this: if a field has previously been set as `VARCHAR(100)` or `VARCHAR(254)` and has content (one IP address per line), is there likely to be data loss? My understanding of `VARCHAR` is that the data is stored at the start (leftmost) and changes in size take place at the end (rightmost), so `MODIFY` would make its changes from the end and leave the data intact, being at the start. As far as versions are concerned it's various versions of MySQL from 4.1 to current.

I'm pretty confident that I can shrink `ip` to `VARCHAR(45)` without zapping existing data. All that said, I'm still pretty new to this and would appreciate an additional pair of eyes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can test the maximum length of current data. With `SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(column)) FROM tablename;` If that max is 45 or less, you have no problem.

Comment: Thanks, ypercube - I don't have access to the database in question, or rather not to all instances of it. My local test setup has passed the tests and nothing exceeded the 45 character boundary. Other instances? I can't tell - and that's my concern. If I am certain it's *only* IP addresses being written, then it stands to reason that it's safe to shrink, but if there's *any* risk then I can't do it.

Comment: You should test of course any column before modifying it. And even more important, backup the databases before doing anything on them. I'd say even better, backup all the databases and tables you need, restore them in a new instance you can play around and try the conversions there. If anything goes wrong, you have done it in a copy, not the original.

Comment: Somebody must be running these scripts. Get them to check if you can't/aren't allowed to. Pass the buck, avoid blame - best policy every time! Joking aside, either you have to run it or someone else does. Give them clear instructions and if they're worried, then tell them you require access. Nobody can fault you for that.

Comment: @Pete Cooper To add more security- make sure you have `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` or `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` in the `sql_mode` enabled. Otherwise, date may be truncated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should properly examine the data metrics

Lengths of ip values greater than 45

```
SELECT IFNULL(LENGTH(ip),'Total'),COUNT(1) rowcount FROM mytable
GROUP BY LENGTH(ip) HAVING LENGTH(ip) > 45 WITH ROLLUP;
```

Suggested data type for ip using [**PROCEDURE ANALYSE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/procedure-analyse.html)

```
SELECT ip FROM mytable PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```

Whatever `SELECT ip FROM mytable PROCEDURE ANALYSE();` reports is what you should use instead of just picking `VARCHAR(45)`.

GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Thanks, RolandoMySQLDBA - I'll try that out. Appreciate it!